# How to destroy a golang sub process on Android?

Tags: android, go, subprocess, kill-process

Recently, I am trying Android sub process with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` and found that I can destroy a NodeJS http server but cannot destroy a Go http server.

for `node` and `go` binary, it is available from Termux;

- node http server: https://github.com/stallpool/halfbase/tree/master/nodejs/tinyserver/index.js
- go http server: https://github.com/stallpool/halfbase/blob/master/golang/tinyserver/main.go

For node sub process, it can be started in an Android `Service` and `p.waitFor()`; when it is time, it can be killed by `p.destroy()`

However, for go sub process, it can be started but cannot be killed by `p.destroy()` even `p. destroyForcibly()`; in this article https://medium.com/honestbee-tw-engineer/gracefully-shutdown-in-go-http-server-5f5e6b83da5a , it makes sure a go server can be closed gracefully and I tried it but `p.destroy()` still does not work.

It is appreciated if anyone can light me a way to kill the process. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just figured out a hack way; not elegant; guide me to a better solution if any!

```
Log.d("AppDebug", p.javaClass.getName())
// from above log
// we can know Android use "java.lang.UNIXProcess" as implementation of java.lang.Process

// to make sure the sub process is killed eventually
if (p.isAlive()) {
    val klass = p.javaClass
    if (klass.getName().equals("java.lang.UNIXProcess")) {
        Log.d("AppDebug", "force terminate sub process ..")
        try {
            val f = klass.getDeclaredField("pid");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            val pid = f.getInt(p);
            // XXX: buggy here, if getInt throw an error, the filed is exposed!
            f.setAccessible(false);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            Log.d("AppDebug", "force terminating done.")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("AppDebug", "force terminating failed.")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("AppDebug", "force terminating not supported.")
    }
}
```

---

sorry for my misleading. currently I totally understand why my go server cannot be killed after I add some log about `ps -ef` before/after kill the process.

actually I use `go run main.go` to start the server; however, `go run main.go` will compile the code and generate a binary file in tmp folder; then it will spawn a child process (execute the binary); when I did `p.destroy()`, it merely kill the `go` process but the child server process remains there.

the correct solution is, get `pid` like above code; and use `ps -o pid= --ppid=<pid>` to get children tree and kill all processes for a cleanup.